# Creating A Stylesheet Switcher Live Preview WP Customizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, stylesheet, css

**Backstory:**

I created a stylesheet switcher using the native WordPress Customizer.  I have the customizer functioning properly and saving the new stylesheet selection via php, but for the live preview via .js/jQuery, I'm having problems.  Hoping you can give me some pointers, still new to .js and jQuery.

**My Problem**

When I select a scheme from my dropdown and click 'publish' in the customizer, then refresh, my changes appear, so I'm good on the php side, but when I make the selection in the WP Customizer Live Preview iframe, my changes don't appear at all.

When I go into console, I can see that my selected scheme has been selected with the proper url path to the stylesheet I selected, yet nothing appears on screen.

**My .js/jQuery:**

```
wp.customize( 'my_scheme_switch', function( value ) {
value.bind( function( to ) {
var zScheme;

    if ( 'default' === to ) {

        zScheme = 'default.css';

    } else if ( 'orange' === to ) {

        zScheme = 'orange.css';

    } else {

        zScheme = 'default.css';

    }

    jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
        var $body = $( 'body' );
        var $head = $( 'head' );

        var $switcher = $('#my-style-switcher-css', $head );
        var schemes = '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/schemes/';
        var newStyle = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + schemes + zScheme;
        $switcher.href = newStyle;
    });  
});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to [so], vegaskev. You have to define `"I'm having problems"`... error messages, expected result...

Comment: b__, thank you for your reply.  I should've had that in there from the beginning.

Comment: Check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104671 and follow the link

Comment: Thanks for the link b__, much appreciated, unfortunately, though, that's for changing individual elements (though you can change it to include multiple styles).  What I'm trying to do is have this link to a completely different stylesheet altogether.  By following the method in those links, I would have to write all of my styles for the stylesheet in the .js file so that they would be seen live, which means any stylesheet changes in the future would also have to be coded in the .js file.   I just need to find a way that the live preview will switch to the selected stylesheet.

Comment: You're using `jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {} )` differently from Otto's example.

Comment: Yes, I am.  I haven't said that i was using it the same.  I'm unsure about the purpose of your response, could you please elaborate on your thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience with the Customizer, was only pointing out a [Core Developer's tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/). And, that at first sight, he wraps everything inside [jQuery noConflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers), while you are doing it ***inside*** `wp.customize` function. That seems strange to me. But this is as much as I can offer, hope you find a solution.